# Using JavaScript to redirect a page

Tags: list, javascript, security

I am using JavaScript to redirect users who aren't owners to a different page.  I am using

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        //check owner status
        if(!isOwner)
        {
        window.location.replace("/sharepoint/website/lists/other.aspx");
        }
    });
```

My problem is that the list is loading before the redirect happens, and my more savvy users may be able to stop the page from redirecting and look over it.  Is there something else I should be using so that I don't load the page first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead content area set to run at server.  By getting rid of the $(document).ready(function() and putting in the script I was able to get the page to redirect without loading the list data.

Answer (score 1):

A work around would be to audience target the list view web part on the list to point to your owners group. It will be hidden from non-owners and you could still use the javascript redirect.